# Crontab style scheduling in Play 2.4.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, cron, scheduled-tasks

Technically I can install cron on the machine and curl the url, but I'm trying to avoid that. Any way to accomplish this?

Reason I want to avoid cron is so I can easily change the schedule or stop it completely without also ssh'ing into the machine to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at: https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler.
Refer to http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/CronExpression.html for valid CronExpressions and examples.

An example taken from the docs:

An example schedule called Every-30-Seconds which, aptly, fires-off every 30 seconds:

```
akka {
  quartz {
    schedules {
      Every30Seconds {
        description = "A cron job that fires off every 30 seconds"
        expression = "*/30 * * ? * *"
        calendar = "OnlyBusinessHours"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can integrate this into your Play! application (probably in your Global application)

Comment: yeah i was looking at that as well. i thought there was something that was built in to play which i could work with, i remember there was this "Job" class which was removed...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Akka scheduler.

```
val scheduler = Akka.system(app).scheduler
scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 hour) {
  // run this block every hour
}
```

The first parameter is a delay, so if you wanted to delay to a specific time you could easily calculate the target time with some simple date arithmetic.

Comment: scheduler i know, im more looking for something that allows me to run something like "40 06 * * 1-5"

Comment: From https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler: "Akka's default scheduler also is executed around a HashedWheelTimer – a potential precision loss for jobs, as it does not provide strong guarantees on the timeliness of execution."

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/philcali/cronish

Some example code from `README.md`:

```
val payroll = task {
  println("You have just been paid... Finally!")
}

// Yes... that's how you run it 
payroll executes "every last Friday in every month"

val greetings = job (println("Hello there")) describedAs "General Greetings"

// give a delayed start
val delayed = greetings runs "every day at 7:30" in 5.seconds

// give an exact time to start
val exact = greetings runs "every day at noon" starting now + 1.week

// resets a job to its definition 
val reseted = exact.reset()

reseted starting now + 1.day
```

Comment: that looks so easy to use! starred!